# Image doesn't show up when it's last in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-linearlayout

This has puzzled me for two days now. I have a LinearLayout like the following:

```
        <LinearLayout
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect_wht_bg"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:minHeight="30dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:visibility="gone">
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/timage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    />
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tname"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ticon" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

The last ImageView (ticon) doesn't showup.  I only see timage and tname. But, if I switched it:

```
<LinearLayout>
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/ticon" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/timage" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tname" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It's there.  What is going on here?

Comment: Is that normal that your sample code shows an android:visibility="gone" on your layout ?

Comment: Is the TextView width squeezing it out past the width of the screen? Also, I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I'm not sure the scaleType makes sense with the first ImageView if you're just don't wrap_content for its height & width anyway.

Comment: AsTeR: yes, it's normal. It's part of a larger layout where there's different components showing different things. Depending on what users are seeing, we show them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're defining the layout_height of your TextView as "fill_parent", it will take the remaining space. That's why it shows properly if it's declared last: the images use only the space they need (layout_height="wrap_content").

Depending on what you want to do, you can either try setting the layout_height of the TextView to "wrap_content" or, if you want the TextView to fill up the space between the images, I would suggest you to use RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     ...>
     <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/timage"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          ...
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
     <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/ticon"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          ...
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/tname"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          ...
          android:layout_below="@+id/timage"
          android:layout_above="@+id/ticon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah. I ended up using RelativeLayout. It still remains a mystery why the last ImageView not showing up on LinearLayout. Probably an Android bug.

Answer (score 2):

The content of your `TextView` might be pushing out the `ImageView`. Try using `layout_weight="1"` to distribute all of the remaining space to the `TextView`.